# Loop certain IF statements in java

Tags: java, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of sides");

        number = input.nextInt();  

    if (number == 1) {
        System.out.println("Circle");
    }

    if (number == 3) {
        System.out.println("Triangle");
    }

    if (number == 4) {
        System.out.println("quadrilateral");

    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Input");
}
}

}
```

Hello, I am trying to use the `if` statement. Can anyone advise me how to loop `if` statements? Because I get this as a result for example: 
circle
Incorrect Input.

Also, How could I repeat the scanner so it allowed me to type another input?

Comment: use `else if`'s

Comment: Can I still do: else if (number == 3) so on

Comment: Simply make a for or while loop and put those if statements and your scanner prompt inside of it. Also you need else if

Comment: @PetrCina Yes, you can.

Comment: I dont really get the question. Your trying to loop the scanner prosses? `Use while(){ your code }`

Comment: Change all your `if`s to `if-else`.

Comment: Since a number can't be meanwhile ==1 and ==3, else-ifs are more appropriate. When you have conditions, which don't exclude each other if (a < 3) ... if (a > 0), you normally don't use else.

Comment: I dont think he/she knows what a while loop is. We better show them

Comment: @CardinalSystem: And except for changing the others to else-if, not if-else. :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the `else` clause is only associated to the last `if` block i.e. `if (number == 4) {...}` This means if any of the other if blocks are executed, it will still print "Incorrect Input". The solution is to use `else if` instead of separate if's.

```
if (number == 1) {
     System.out.println("Circle");
}else if (number == 3) {
     System.out.println("Triangle");
}else if (number == 4) {
     System.out.println("quadrilateral");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Incorrect Input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch` `case` (see : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

And you can check the type of number or string with `instanceof`.

Comment: I like this solution. But you still need to answer and question about loops.

Comment: oh yeah don't see that ^^. if loop :/

Answer (score -1):

For your second part question, I guess you're looking for something like a do....while loop, you can set up some condition like if the input result is not a number, then it will stuck in the loop until the user type in a number then only go in the the if, else-if statement